# Unable to get OpenCV 3.1 FPS over ~15 FPS

Tags: python, c++, opencv, video, camera

I have some extremely simple performance testing code below for measuring the FPS of my webcam with OpenCV 3.1 + Python3 on a Late 2011 Macbook Pro:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
count = 0
start_time = time.perf_counter()
end_time = time.perf_counter()
while (start_time + 1) > end_time:
    count += 1
    cap.read()
    # Attempt to force camera FPS to be higher
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 30)
    end_time = time.perf_counter()
print("Got count", count)
```

Doing no processing, not even displaying the image or doing this in another thread, I am only getting around 15 FPS.

Trying to access the FPS of the camera with cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS) I get 0.0.

Any ideas why?

I've already searched the internet a fair amount for answers, so things I've thought about:

- I build OpenCV with release flags, so it shouldn't be doing extra debugging logic
- Tried manually setting the FPS each frame (see above)
- My FPS with other apps (e.g. Camera toy in Chrome) is 30FPS
- There is no work being done in the app on the main thread, so putting the video capture logic in another thread as most other posts suggest shouldn't make a difference

** EDIT ** 
Additional details: it seems like the first frame I capture is quick, then subsequent frames are slower; seems like this could be a buffer issues (i.e. the camera is being paused after the first frame because a new buffer must be allocated to write to?)

Tweaked the code to calculate the average FPS so far after each read:

```
 cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB, False)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 30)
start_time = time.perf_counter()
count = 0
cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS
end_time = time.perf_counter()
while True:
    count += 1
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    end_time = time.perf_counter()
    print("Reached FPS of: ", count / (end_time - start_time))
```

And I get one frame around 30FPS, and then subsequent frames are slower:

Reached FPS of:  27.805818385257446

Reached FPS of:  19.736237223924398

Reached FPS of:  18.173748156583795

Reached FPS of:  17.214809956810114

Reached FPS of:  16.94737657138959

Reached FPS of:  16.73624509452099

Reached FPS of:  16.33156408530572

** EDIT ** 
Still no luck as of 10/20. My best bet is there are some issues with memory transfer since the camera itself can definitively capture at 30 FPS based on the ability of other apps.

Comment: What is your camera's default resolution, Format ? Have you checked the same in other apps?

Comment: also check this http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html

Comment: Show your capture+render code please

Comment: my build-in camera (in Asus) gives `-1` for `cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS` but `25.0` for `cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT` :) probably some issue in CV code

Comment: Have you tried to disable CV_CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB? I see this bug https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/4831
May be this causes your FPS slower.

Comment: @BalajiR 1280x720 (same resolution as the screen and the same recording resolution as photobooth and other apps when they're getting 30FPS)

Comment: @Micka This is the only code I am using at this point; I am trying to isolate the problem down to the bare-minimum to ensure no rendering logic is causing it to slow down further.

Adding a simple imshow after the read doesn't have a significant impact it seems on the recorded FPS

Comment: @khôinguyễn Just tried that, thanks for the idea - unfortunately didn't really change things

Comment: did you try setting fps only once before the loop?

Comment: can you try to capture like 100 seconds and divide the counter by 100 in the end?

Comment: if you remove "ret, frame = cap.read()" what's the fps of just querying the timer and printing the fps?

Comment: @Micka Yes, the FPS is about the same over 100 seconds vs. 1 seconds; what's perhaps more interesting is the per-frame-FPS; that varies wildly between 20FPS and 9FPS after the first frame which is around 30FPS

Comment: @Micka Also tried just setting FPS once (see edit).

If you mean how many times the python loops without doing the cap.read, it is ~3 million times in 1 second

Comment: if you remove both: cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB, False)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 30) does this change anything in performance?

Comment: @Micka Nope.

I'm really curious about that first 'fast frame' - it consistently appears and is around the FPS I would expect of the camera (~30) which makes me thing there must be some issue which affects trying to to multiple frames in a row.

Comment: from my understanding, the first frame should have no delay at all... so the time interval between start_time and the first print should be much less than 33ms ...

Comment: can you try to get the property CV_CAP_PROP_BUFFERSIZE? And/or set that property to 4?

Comment: @Micka Why should the first frame have no delay vs. others? It seems you should still have to sample from the camera and copy the data into a matrix.

Comment: @Micka tried setting the buffer size to something larger; doesn't seem to make any difference :/. When I get the property, I get 0.0, so I am guessing it isn't supported by my setup.

Answer (score 2):

IT'S NOT ANSWER. Since the comment in original question is too long for your attention. I post outside instead.

First, it's normal when CV_CAP_PROP_FPS return 0. OpenCV for Python just a wrapper for OpenCV C++. As far as I know, this property only works for video file, not camera. You have to calculate FPS yourself (like your edited).

Second, OpenCV have a bug that always convert the image get from camera to RGB https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/4831. Normal camera usually use YUYV color. It's take a lot of time. You can check all supported resolution + fps https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Webcam. I see some camera not support RGB color and OpenCV force to get RGB and take terrible FPS. Due to camera limitation, in the same codec, the higher resolution, the slower fps. In different supported codec, the bigger output in same resolution, the slower fps. For example, my camera support yuyv and mjpeg, in HD resolution, YUYV have max 10 fps while MJPEG have max 30 fps.

So, first you can try ffmpeg executable to get frames. After identifying where error come from, if ffmpeg works well, you can use ffmpeg library (not ffmpeg executable) to get frame from your camera (OpenCV using ffmpeg for most video I/O including camera).

Be aware that the I only work with ffmpeg and OpenCV in C++ language, not Python. Using ffmpeg library is another long story.

Good luck!